# Joomla manifest file menu link

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I want to create a manifest file, in which I want to set the default link when clicking on the menu, how should I phrase the link "anoption=avalue"?

```
<menu link="anoption=avalue">COM_EXAMPLE_SUBMENU_ANOPTION</menu>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to go in this way :

`<menu view="`**view_name**`">`**Text_To_Show_On_Menu_Link**`</menu>`

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: is it <menu view="listing">Text_To_Show_On_Menu_Link</menu> or <menu view="view_listing">Text_To_Show_On_Menu_Link</menu>? Cause it does not work..

Comment: If your view name is listing then you have to use this <menu view="listing">Text_To_Show_On_Menu_Link</menu>